# How to get username from objectID for Parse in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, for-loop, parse-platform

I have the user's unique ID, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the username from the Parse Data Base with this info. I'm storing the ID's in an array, and I've tried to loop through it but i don't know where to go from there. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to get the current user or a user other then current?

Comment: I'm trying to get other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple here you go!

```
NSArray *arrayOfUsersObjectIDs = ...;
PFQuery *queryForUsers = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Your_Class_Name"];
[queryForUsers whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:arrayOfUsersObjectIDs];
[queryForUsers findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if(!error) {
        for(PFObject *objUser in objects) {
            NSLog(@"User name: %@", objects[@"Key_For_Name"]);
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: I don't think you should use `findObjects` this just creates an additional step. All the OP has to do is use `getObjectInBackgroundWithId` since he already has the id that returns only 1 object, the only one that matters sense you have an ID already, although this isn't a wrong answer, just FYI.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did find a small error in your code, objects in your NSLog statement should be the name of the PFObject, so in this case its:    objUser[@"Key_For_Name]);